# Save local ggplot graphics and use in reactable table

Tags: r, ggplot2, reactable

I'd like to generate small ggplot graphics and use them inline in a `reactable`. I can generate the plots needed (1 per row), but when inserting them into the table, they come up as broken images. I imagine it has something to do with the file paths?

*Note*: This will ultimately be used in a shiny app where the graphics are generated dynamically. I am doing this in `reactable` because I plan to combine this with the expandable rows feature.

Here is some reproducible code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)
library(reactable)

#get list of species names
species <- penguins %>% select(species ) %>%
  distinct() %>% pull()

# make a simple df
plot_data <- penguins %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(bill_length_mm, na.rm=T))

# for loop to generate and save plots
for(i in species){
  tmp_plot <- 
    plot_data %>%
    filter(species == i) %>%
    ggplot(aes(y=species, x=mean))+
    geom_col()+
    theme_void()
  
  file_name <- i %>% janitor::make_clean_names()
  
  ggsave(plot = tmp_plot,
         filename = paste0("plots/",file_name,".png"),
         width=4,
         height=.5)
  
}

#make a table
species %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rename("species" = 1) %>%
  mutate(plot = paste0("<img src='plots/", janitor::make_clean_names(species),".png' />")) %>%
  reactable(
    columns = list(
      plot = colDef(html = TRUE,
                    resizable = TRUE,
                    show=T)
    ))
```

Here is what I get:
[image]

Just as a check, doing this loads the graphic: `magick::image_read("plots/adelie.png")` so I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Have you figured something out yet?